# CSS - Animation hover issue

Tags: animation, css

I have this issue with getting an animation working only if the user hovers over a div.
I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HBfLY/1/

So I want it to bounce in from the left, but instead it is blinking. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If the element moves from under the cursor, it's no longer hovered, therefore the `:hover` selector no longer matches that element; use a different target for the `:hover` interaction.

Comment: ok. you're so right. how did I missed that?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is that, once the element changes its position due to the animation, it's no longer hovered-over by the cursor, therefore the `:hover` selector no longer applies.

To remedy this you could apply the `:hover` to an ancestor element:

```
body:hover #animatie1 {
    border: 5px solid black;
    position:relative;
    top: 20px;
    left:100px;
    width:100px;
    height: 200px;
    animation:mymove 2s ;
    -moz-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Opera */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HBfLY/4/).

Or use a preceding sibling element:

```
#immediatelyPrecedingSibling:hover + #animatie1 {
    border: 5px solid black;
    position:relative;
    top: 20px;
    left:100px;
    width:100px;
    height: 200px;
    animation:mymove 2s ;
    -moz-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Opera */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HBfLY/5/).

In those browsers that support the general-sibling combinator, you could use *any* preceding sibling element (so long as you can target it with CSS, and, to reiterate, that this sibling *precedes the element to be targeted in the DOM*):

```
#notAnImmediatelyPrecedingSibling:hover ~ #animatie1 {
    border: 5px solid black;
    position:relative;
    top: 20px;
    left:100px;
    width:100px;
    height: 200px;
    animation:mymove 2s ;
    -moz-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:mymove 2s ; /* Opera */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HBfLY/6/).

References:

- [Browser support for general sibling `~` combinator](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t30).
- [CSS Level 3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Comment: @Claudiu, you're very welcome, and I'm glad to have been of help! I was going to just leave it as a comment, then I realised that there was a little more information to add, and some viable suggestions to be made; so I answered. Which is, hopefully far more useful! And, sincerely, my thanks for the accept! =)